Which aerodiesels comply with MOSAIC?
MOSAIC will, presumably, expand the list of type certified aircraft operable by a pilot with a sport license.
Current Light Sport regulations result in a countable number of type-certified aircraft legally operable by a light sport pilot - almost exclusively tail dragger soft-bodies: Aeronca's Chief, Superchief, and Champ; Ercoupe 415; Interstate Cadet; Luscombe 8; Piper Cub and Cub Special; Porterfield Collegiate; Quicksilver GT500 (Technically a kit, but they'll sell it to you ready to fly); and Taylorcraft's Cub, B, D and L-2 Grasshopper.
The MOSAIC expanded list is basically anything with a clean stall 54 knots or less - and will include several purpose-built aircraft designed to break into the anticipated market.
A comprehensive list of MOSAIC-compliant type certified airplanes would be too long to ask for, but I'm interested in learning more about single prop aerodiesels (either stock or with STC that doesn't cost as much as the plane itself) that would be flyable under MOSAIC - if any yet exist.
When I attempt to look up single prop aerodiesels, I'm unable to easily find their clean stall speed (Vs1).  For example, the Tecnam P2010 gives a stall speed, but it's flaps down, power off, which is not part of the MOSAIC rules.
I'm am looking for a list of MOSAIC-compliant, a consistently easy way to find a given candidate aircraft's clean stall speed, or specific candidates that meet the criteria even if the list is not exhaustive (in that order of preference).
The criteria are:

Single-prop
Four seat max
Clean stall 54 knots or less

